# Display bootstrap banner constantly until user click 'X' mark

Tags: php, session, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display a boostrap banner in my page until user close that by clicking 'x' mark in that.

I displayed that banner by using session variable. If the session contain value the banner will be display otherwise it should not be display.

```
<?php if ($status && $status<>'' ) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" id="banner-close">&times;</a>
        <strong><?php echo $status?></strong>
    </div>
    <?php $newdata['status'] = ''; $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
} ?>
```

Here I will display the banner only if the status var contain value. The status is a session variable.

Comment: Ok, good logic. But what you want? and where is your code?

Comment: With php, you would only be able to do this on page load. Otherwise, you would need to use a client side scripting language such as JavaScript

Comment: Hi, here i have added my code     <?php 
                
  if ($status && $status<>'' )
  {
 ?>

  
   <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" id="banner-close">&times;</a>
      <strong><?php echo $status?></strong>
   </div>
   
        <?php 
                $newdata['status'] = '';
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata); 
                }
        ?>  Here i will display the banner only if the status var contain value. The status is a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this client-side, I would suggest [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Once you have included jQuery into your page, something like the code below will handle the click event that you need to capture to hide your banner;

```
$("div").on("click","#banner-close",function(e){
    //put jquery code in here to hide/show banner, for example...
    $(".alert").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

If you add more of your html into your question (i.e. banner markup) then this code example can be improved, but this is the general principal.